# How can i assign the output of a makefile function to a variable

Tags: shell, makefile, google-cloud-composer

I have a function in a makefile that returns a bucket name in google cloud storage

```
define get_composer_bucket
    gcloud beta composer environments describe --location=europe-west2 ${COMPOSER_SANDBOX_NAME} \
    | grep -hnr "dagGcsPrefix"
endef
```

I want to use the output of this in a makefile command. How can i assign the output of this to a variable? I have tried the below, which returns an empty variable. Am i doing something wrong?

```
run:

    BUCKET=$(call get_composer_bucket)  
    echo ${BUCKET}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many SO answers that will describe to you the difference between *make* variables and *shell* variables; knowing this difference is crucial to writing makefiles.

There are also many SO answers that will explain that each command in a recipe is run in a different shell, and that variables set in one shell can't be passed to another shell, so setting a variable in one recipe command line can't be seen in another recipe command line (you can use `\` to combine multiple physical lines into a single logical line, but you probably need to add `;` as well to satisfy the shell).

And, there are many answers discussing how a makefile is not a shell script (although it can CONTAIN shell scripts) so you can't just write a shell script anywhere in a makefile and have it evaluated.

The simplest thing to do for you is to set a *make* variable using the make `shell` function to run the shell script:

```
BUCKET := $(shell gcloud beta composer environments describe --location=europe-west2 ${COMPOSER_SANDBOX_NAME} | grep -hnr "dagGcsPrefix")

run:
         echo $(BUCKET)
```

Of course, this is different in various ways than what you tried to do above.  So maybe it doesn't meet your requirements, but you haven't actually stated what those are.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code which will help you to extract the name

```
define get_composer_bucket
    `gcloud beta composer environments describe --location=europe-west2 ${COMPOSER_SANDBOX_NAME} \
    | grep -hnr "dagGcsPrefix"`
endef
BUCKET:= $(call get_composer_bucket)
run:
    @echo "BUCKET=> $(BUCKET)"
```